# Ldap: Listening to changes done externally

Tags: java, ldap, opendj

I have a Java web application using Opendj LDAP server to manage the users. Users can be added to either through Web Application or LDap server UI. Is there anyway for Web Application to get notified when user is added/edited from LDap server UI? Currently, the users are being refreshed in Web Application at a regular interval by getting all the users from LDap server. Is there any listener kind of thing that monitors users on Ldap? Anything in Ldap SDK I can make use?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OpenDJ supports the LDAP Persistent Search control that allows an application to register and receive entries and/or changes when they occur. The OpenDJ SDK has support for the control, but JNDI and other SDK do support the control as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JNDI you can use a [NamingListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/event/NamingListener.html) or one of its sub-interfaces, if the server supports notifications. Other LDAP SDKs should have comparable features.